# Erro na página xml do android

Tags: android, xml

Sou muito iniciante em android e seguindo rigorosamente o exemplo disponibilizado por meu professor e usando um PC da Faculdade eu copiei e colei e não tive problemas, usando o meu notebook estou com o seguinte erro:

> Error:(1) No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'paddingLeft' with value '@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin').

A declaração do xml está assim:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

O mesmo erro acontece pros outros paddings. Como posso resolver ?

Comment: Remove esses paddings que não tem problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ele está dando essa mensagem por que não encontrou a informação solicitada em `android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"`, dentro do arquivo `res/values/dimens.xml` você pode definir essa informação.

Ex.:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Local do arquivo dentro do diretório:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]